# Сортировка в Model.objects.all() по умолчанию

Tags: python, django

Писал я сайт на django. И обратил внимание, что `User.objects.all()` выдает мне пользователей не по порядку.

То есть, например, есть у меня пользователь с `id=1` Саша, есть с `id=2` Паша, с `id=3` Маша, с `id=4` Даша. И `User.objects.all()` мне выдает их в порядке 3, 2, 1, 4 вместо 1, 2, 3, 4. Вопрос, почему? По какому критерию джанго сортирует из коробки?

PS: я знаю про `order_by` и что я могу переопределить поле для сортировки по умолчанию в `Meta` класса. Мне интересно просто как это делает непосредственно `User.objects.all()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не Django их сортирует по какому-то критерию, это он их так от СУБД получает. В соответствии со стандартом SQL, если в запросе явно не определена сортировка, порядок результатов может быть произвольным.

Если есть желание определить сортировку по умолчанию, то это [можно сделать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#ordering) в мета-классе модели:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_field = models...
    another_field = models...

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['some_field']
```

Comment: Ясно, буду знать. Интересный стандарт SQL...